# Navbar Toggler Not Working on Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using the latest bootstrap 4, on this navigation bar I want to use the toggler button on medium to small screen. However, the button isn't not working and not showing the menu item.

wrap in (nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top")

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationCollapse">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navigationCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="list-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes - First, `<li class="list-item">` to  `<li class="nav-item">`  and second `id="#navigationCollapse"` to `id="navigationCollapse"`. We use # only where we are referring to this id.

Additionally i used `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top">` as nav.

[View JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5so7fxa/3/)